# React router not rendering inactive route components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I started with create-react-app and am attempting to set up auth-based routing via a `Gatekeeper` component. Right now the only thing the `Gatekeeper` component does is render its children. I use redux to get the current user from the state tree and save it as `currentUser`. I'll use that to validate access to the child routes later.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { subscribeToCurrentUser } from '../../reducers/authentication';

class Gatekeeper extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.subscribeToCurrentUser();
    }

    render() {
        return this.props.children
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        currentUser: state.currentUser
    }
}

const GatekeeperContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, {subscribeToCurrentUser})(Gatekeeper);

export default GatekeeperContainer;
```

If I initially load the app on, say `/account` everything loads as expected. But if I navigate to `/templates/123` via a `<NavLink>` the URL changes but the `<Template>` component doesn't render. Inspecting with React Dev Tools shows me the children of every route underneath the `Gatekeeper` component is `null`. If I refresh the page then the `<Template>` component renders as expected but navigating back to `/account` doesn't render the `<AccountPage>` component.

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
            <Layout>
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Gatekeeper>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} />
                        <Route path="/templates/:templateID" component={Template} />
                        <Route path="/account" component={AccountPage} />
                    </Switch>
                </Gatekeeper>
            </Layout>
        </div>
    </Router>
</Provider>
```

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: Does it render emptiness or it persists the previous component?

Comment: which version of react router are you using? if it's v4 then i don't think there's any problem with the code you posted above, the problem could be elsewhere.

Comment: @GProst it persists the previous component. If I navigate to a route outside of `<Gatekeeper>` such as `/login` it changes routes and renders the appropriate component as expected though.

Comment: @AhmedWagdi I'm using version 4.1.1.

Comment: Any errors may be? And your <NavLink> is just a wrapper to a <Link>?
Can you show your <Gatekeeper /> component code? Just to be sure...

Comment: @GProst There are no console errors. I updated the question with full `<Gatekeeper>` code. `<NavLink>` is part of react router that lets you add styles if that link's path is the active path.

Comment: This structure works for me. There should be something else...